# Как удалить "лишние" головы из репозитария в Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, hg

Веду свой проект с помощью системы контроля версий Mercurial. Так как начал совсем недавно осваивать системы управления версиями, то возникают некоторый вопросы. В частности, почему при попытке запушить изменения в хранилище командой hg push иногда Mercurial говорит, что это невозможно сделать, так данная операция создаст новую голову в отдаленном хранилище? Приходится использовать hg push с ключом -f. И вот стал вопрос, как удалить "лишние" и мне ненужные головы, коих накопилось уже с десяток?

Answer (score 1):

> В частности, почему при попытке запушить изменения в хранилище
>   командой hg push иногда Mercurial говорит, что это невозможно сделать,
>   так данная операция создаст новую голову в отдаленном хранилище?

Перед выгрузкой своих изменений забирайте другие из удаленного репозитория `hg pull -u` и если образовалась вторая голова, то сделайте слияние изменений через `hg merge` затем `hg commit -m "merge"` и `hg push`

Коммит который вы создаете на локальной машине не известен удаленному репозиторию, соответственно дальнейшая нумерация ревизий отличается от тех, которые находятся в удаленном репозитории. Перед отправкой изменений вам нужно актуализировать / синхронизировать свою копию репозитория с удаленной. Если вы отправляете изменения в режиме `force`, то проблемы слияния изменений будет решать другой разработчик, а это плохо.

P.S Если у вас накопился десяток "голов", то их нужно все слить (смерджить) в одну. Посмотрите какие головы находятся в вашей ветке `hg heads имя_ветки` (получить имя ветки можно через `hg branch`) и выполните слияние с остальными головами `hg merge номер_или_хэш_ревизии`

Comment: Что-то я не так делаю, наверное:

Comment: Что-то я не так делаю, наверное.
Команда "hg heads default" возвращает:

набор изм-й:   207:e233ee98c982
метка:         tip
автор:         Юрий Иванов <gorodage@gmail.com>
дата:          Tue Jan 26 17:22:36 2016 +0300
сводка:        При первом запуске программы удалить файл program.ini, если таковой присутствует.

...

..._

Попытка "hg merge 207:e233ee98c982" возвращает "прервано: uncommitted changes" или "слияние с рабочим каталогом не имеет смысла"